# how can I get the full url of a href attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

```
<a id="next" href="/housing/__1_0_0_0_1_0_0/">next page</a>
```

when I put the mouse over `href` value, there will be a a link with a full url `"http://esf.zs.fang.com/housing/__1_0_0_0_1_0_0/"`

how can I get the full url instead of the relative url?

I used xpath("//a/@href"),but it only gets the relative url `"/housing/__1_0_0_0_1_0_0/"`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you can read the href property of the dom element

Answer (score 1):

[`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) can give you everything you want to know about the current browser location, which you could use to compose a fully qualified URL.

Answer (score 0):

The `href` **property** contains the full URL:

```
var url = document.getElementById('next').href;
```